# Handling ctrl + c in perl when script ran using setsid

Tags: perl, centos, setsid

My Perl script looks like this

#### A.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
system("perl ctrlc.pl");
```

#### ctrlc.pl

```
sub signal_handler {
    print "Niraj";
}

$SIG{INT} = \&signal_handler;
print "Enter number";

my $no1 = <>;
```

When I run `perl A.pl` and press Ctrl-C it is detecting and printing "Niraj".
But when I run `setsid perl A.pl` , it is not detecting Ctrl-C.

Comment: Note it will handle a SIGINT sent to it (say, using `kill -INT $pid`), but the whole point of `setsid` is to detach the process from the terminal so things like Ctrl-C doesn't affect it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**setsid** creates a new session.

The **SIGINT** signal is sent to the foreground process group of a session associated to the tty. Since the process A.pl is now in a different session, effectively in a different process group, the signals are not received by A.pl.

Answer (score 4):

The `setsid` command starts your perl program in a new session with no controlling terminal. That leaves no way to interact with the process other than by process ID

This is pretty much the point of `setsid` in the first place. If you want to retain control of your program then you should run it without `setsid`